# Make Table with Aggregate query - pivot table workaround access 2013

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Edit: The Short version:

When Attempting to use the following SQL in a make table query I continually get an error that "an action query cannot be used as a row source" What part of this query is an action query? Is there a way to change the query so it will work? I believe it may be caused by the "Count(Eligibility_Applications.[Family Member(s) Enrolled]) AS [CountOfAdditional Related People]" section.

The SQL that I am trying to use is this:

```
SELECT Eligibility_Applications.[Application Date], Eligibility_Applications.[Eligibility Rep], Eligibility_Applications.Clinic, Eligibility_Applications.Outreach, Eligibility_Applications.[Content Type], Eligibility_Applications.Renewal, Eligibility_Applications.[Application Status], Count(Eligibility_Applications.[Family Member(s) Enrolled]) AS [CountOfAdditional Related People], Eligibility_Applications.Related_Person_ID, People.[Patient Status], People.[City of Residence], People.SSN, People.[Content Type] AS [Person Type], IIf([SSN]="999999999","Undocumented","Documented") AS Documented INTO tbl_Test
FROM Eligibility_Applications INNER JOIN People ON Eligibility_Applications.Related_Person_ID = People.ID
GROUP BY Eligibility_Applications.[Application Date], Eligibility_Applications.[Eligibility Rep], Eligibility_Applications.Clinic, Eligibility_Applications.Outreach, Eligibility_Applications.[Content Type], Eligibility_Applications.Renewal, Eligibility_Applications.[Application Status], Eligibility_Applications.Related_Person_ID, People.[Patient Status], People.[City of Residence], People.SSN, People.[Content Type], IIf([SSN]="999999999","Undocumented","Documented")
HAVING (((Count(Eligibility_Applications.[Family Member(s) Enrolled]))>0) AND ((Eligibility_Applications.Related_Person_ID) Is Not Null));
```

Detailed:

Our organization just updated their software from access 2007 to 2013 (which means that pivot tables are no longer possible due to the "upgrade"). I am attempting to do a work around that uses linked information from access to excel.

I have two ways that I view the data. One uses a simple select query and works fine with the excel workaround the other query is an aggregate query that counts the number of entries in a multi-valued field (linked to sharpoint and I am not able to remove/change it). Previously this was the source for the pivot table, and I could use strWhere to change the source when opening the pivot.

Unfortunately if I want to change the records that are sent to excel I need to make a table first (as far as I can figure ot, as I do not think I can both link with excel and dynamically change the SQL of a query). The problem is that when I attempt to change the query to Make Table it does not function stating that "an action query cannot be used as a row source". Is there a way I would be able to make a table that includes a multi-valued field (I only need the number of entries in the field not the actual values)

Is there anyway to make this work? I have not been impressed with the filtering options in excel thus far so I would like to filter in access before opening it up in access, but if there is a better way to filter in excel I am open to it.

Thank you!

Comment: The question is long and not very clear. Please try to reword the question to  have a specific example query along with table information, sample data, expected output etc. Please also try to summarize the three paragraphs of text for easier understanding of your question.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear, please let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful.

Comment: In do not understand, what you are trying to do. In your SQL the "INTO tbl_Test" is the action query part, but that is what you intend to do, isn't it?